# Why does this LO-calc formula with end of month count entries that it shouldn't?

Tags: date, countif, libreoffice-calc

The formula `=IF(ISTEXT(AK4),"Data Gap",COUNTIFS(Date,">"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),Examinee,$A4))` is counting entries from the last day of last month, but to my understanding, it should only be counting entries with dates larger than ">" the end of last month.

Any ideas why? It defies all logic according to my knowledge.

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Welcome! No, it's all logical. The point is that EOMONTH() returns a "pure date", without the fractional part denoting the time during that date. In other words, "midnight, the beginning of the last day of the month." Most likely your Date range contains date-time values, and this is indeed greater than the beginning of the day. Try changing the formula like `...COUNTIFS(Date,">="&(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1),Examinee,$A4))`

Comment: It works! Thank you, @JohnSUN!

So, the same happens here. This is not counting the last day of last month, because it is only counting from midnight that day backwards. I also have to add a +1 when going the other way around, right?
`=IF(ISTEXT(AD3),"Data Gap",COUNTIFS(Date,"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),Date,">="&(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)+1),Examinee,$A3))`

I think this is a very clunky and counterintuitive solution. The date should account for any date prior to midnight of the next day, and not midnight that day. To me, the devs chose the counterintuitive and illogical solution in this case.

Comment: What do you think?

Also, fell free to copy the answer as an answer if you want the credit. I will tick it off.

Comment: Yes, you got it right: when we select a date range between StartDay and FinishDay, the correct comparison is "greater than or equal to StartDay and less than (FinishDay+1)". If you format your Date range as regular numbers, it becomes a little clearer: the integer part of the number is the number of days from the base date, and the fractional part is the time within that day. Comparing numbers is a little more visual than comparing a date with a datetime, but it's really not very difficult. If you look into this problem and prepare an answer to this question, I will gladly upvote the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as @JohnSUN said, EOMONTH takes the numeric value for midnight on the specified day, for it to work, we should reference the day after the end of month with a "+1" argument and tell the function to account for anything equal or bigger to that point of reference.

`=IF(ISTEXT(AK4),"Data Gap",COUNTIFS(Date,">="&(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1),Examinee,$A4))`

It is not the most intuitive formula and you have to keep that detail in mind.